# Properly showing array items from xpath created array in php

Tags: php, xml, xpath, simplexml, xml-namespaces

I am trying to make an rss reader / fetcher / parser, or whatever you want to call it.
The feed url is `http://www.jutarnji.hr/rss`

I have made a php function where everything works except getting an image from an rss item because it is a very complicated rss feed and the only easy way was with xpath which throws an array and I do not know to extract that array by automatism inside the foreach loop to show the image next to each feed item
NOTE: this is not my rss feed, i am trying to fetch someone elses rss feed:

```
function parser($feedURL) {
$rss = simplexml_load_file($feedURL);
$rss->registerXPathNamespace('n', 'http://jutarnji.hr/rss');

$i = 0;
foreach ($rss->entry as $feedItem) {
    $i++;
    $myDate = ($feedItem->updated);
    $dateForm = explode(" ", $myDate);
    if (date("j.n.Y.", strtotime($myDate)) == date("j.n.Y.")) {
    $niceDate = date("H:i", strtotime($myDate));
    }
    else if (date("j.n.Y.", strtotime($myDate)) == date("j.n.Y.", strtotime("yesterday"))) {
    $niceDate = "jučer u " . date("H:i", strtotime($myDate));
    }
    else {
    $niceDate = date("j.n.Y.", strtotime($myDate)) . " u " . date("H:i", strtotime($myDate));  
    }
    $feedurl = ($feedItem->link->attributes()->href);

    $imgUrl = $rss->xpath("//n:link[@rel='enclosure']/@href");  //This throws an array which I cannot extract and use in this foreach loop as well

    $urltoimage = (string)$imgUrl[0][0][1]; // This was my try to atleast get a specific item but not working

    echo "<div class='box'>
        <h3><a target='_blank' href='$feedurl' title='$feedItem->title'>" . $feedItem->title . "</a></h3>
        <p><img src='$urltomage'/>" . $feedItem->description . "</p>
        <p class='belowpost'><img src='images/time.png'/>" . $niceDate. "<a class='cont' target='_blank' href='$feedurl' title='$feedItem->title'>Više</a></p></div>";
    if($i >= 20) break;
} }
```

The problem is somewhere here:

```
$imgUrl = $rss->xpath("//n:link[@rel='enclosure']/@href");  //This throws an array which I cannot extract and use in this foreach loop as well

    $urltoimage = (string)$imgUrl[0][0][1]; // This was my try to atleast get a specific item but not working
```

Any help is appreciated as long as there is no books included lol
Thanks in advance, this is really important to me

Comment: Try do a var_dump of the $imgUrl like this `var_dump($imgUrl);`. Paste what you get in your question. You'll probably find that it is not an array, but a stdObject.

Comment: paste var_dump($imgUrl);

Comment: I think your namespace registration should be `$rss->registerXPathNamespace('n', 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom');` (looking at the feed start `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">`). But is it necessary? When I run `//link[@rel='enclosure']/@href` on http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi with XPath2.0 and the XML source as input, I get all the URLs you are targetting (default namespace?). You can also try `//n:link[@rel='enclosure']/@n:href`

Answer (score 0):

There some mistakes concerning this one line.

```
$imgUrl = $rss->xpath("//n:link[@rel='enclosure']/@href");
```

Assuming you like to  "getting an image from an rss item".
You registered the namespace `http://jutarnji.hr/rss` but the namespace for the link node is  `http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom`.

Your are using the document node `$rss` as as context node for xpath but you need to use the current entry node `$feedItem`. The Xpaht starts with `//` which will look for all links nodes in the whole document even if you use the right context node.

Therefore:
Add the right namespace:

```
 $feedItem->registerXPathNamespace('n', 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom');
```

And than use:

```
$imgUrl = $feedItem->xpath("n:link[@rel='enclosure']/@href");
```

Or (if the link is not a direct child):

```
$imgUrl = $feedItem->xpath(".//n:link[@rel='enclosure']/@href");
```

Than to get the link from first imgUrl:

```
$urltoimage = (string)$imgUrl[0]->href;
```